# Angularjs parse error after upgrade to v1.3.6

Tags: php, angularjs, parsing, woocommerce

I just upgraded my angularjs version from v1.2.15 to v1.3.6 and it broke a piece of code on my e-commerce site.  (Wordpress, Woocommerce, cart page)

I'm getting a parse error on this:

```
{{initarray.<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>.amount}}
```

Previously this would display the amount of a certain item in the cart, which is be incremental.  However the angularjs upgrade to v1.3.6 can no longer parse this code.

The result on the page looks like this:

```
{{initarray.77596958a3b31761962c8b2393cfcfb2.amount}}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Syntax Error: Token '.77596958' is an unexpected token at column 10 of the expression 
[initarray.77596958a3b31761962c8b2393cfcfb2.amount] starting at [.77596958a3b31761962c8b2393cfcfb2.amount].
```

I didn't write this code, so I'm unfamiliar with the array syntax this programmer used, it must not have been ideal because this newer version of ng doesn't like it.

Any guidance is appreciated, ty.

Comment: It doesn't look like a good idea to mix php with js. Anyway what does the initarray contains? could it be just {{initarray['<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>']amount}}, Get the data from an angular service or in the resolve attribute of a route config, in the template access your data inside initarray without any php output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
{{initarray['<?php echo $cart_item_key; ?>'].amount}}
```

Edit: Added single quotes around the php echo and it works.